# Fragments not inflating menu after switching back and forth

Tags: android, menu, android-fragments, android-actionbar

I'm completely new to android programming, so I'll try to explain this issue as accurately as possible.

I have an application that consists of a MainActivity. This activity houses 3 fragments being controlled using a ViewPager and a FragmentPagerAdapter. When I initially click (through the action bar) or swipe over to the settings fragment, my "Save" and "Cancel" options appear in the action bar. However when I slide away from the fragment (via a swipe), then slide back, the menu fails to load. No matter how many times I move to different fragments and regardless of how I do so (both through tabs and swiping), the menu will not return until the app has either closed or rotated.

However, I've checked the logs and no error seems to be throw, but when I place Debug outputs into OnCreateOptionsMenu I can see that it is indeed getting called. Even stranger, if I rotate the display, the menu appears, and OnCreateOptionsMenu is called a couple more times. I also checked visibility and it shows the items is both visible and enabled. It's almost as if the item is being drawn off the screen.

SettingsFragment.java

```
public class SettingsFragment extends Fragment implements TextWatcher {
    private EditText txtCost;
    private String current = "";

    private DatePicker dtDateQuit;
    private TimePicker dtTimeQuit;

    public SettingsFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_settings, container, false);

        NumberPicker np = (NumberPicker) rootView.findViewById(R.id.npCigs);
        np.setMaxValue(100);
        np.setMinValue(0);

        txtCost = (EditText)rootView.findViewById(R.id.txtCost);
        txtCost.addTextChangedListener(this);

        dtDateQuit = (DatePicker)rootView.findViewById(R.id.dtQuit);
        dtTimeQuit = (TimePicker)rootView.findViewById(R.id.tmQuit);

        txtCost.setText("$" + String.valueOf(MainActivity.dblCost) + "0");
        dtDateQuit.updateDate(MainActivity.dtStopDate.get(Calendar.YEAR),MainActivity.dtStopDate.get(Calendar.MONTH), MainActivity.dtStopDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
        dtTimeQuit.setCurrentHour(MainActivity.dtStopDate.get(Calendar.HOUR));
        dtTimeQuit.setCurrentMinute(MainActivity.dtStopDate.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
        np.setValue(MainActivity.intCigDay);

        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater)
    {
        System.out.println("-------------- Starting Inflation --------------");
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.settings_fragment_menu, menu);
        System.out.println("-------------- Inflation Finished --------------");

        System.out.println("------------ Menu Item: " + menu.getItem(0).getTitle());
        System.out.println("------------ Visible: " +menu.getItem(0).isVisible() );
        System.out.println("------------ Enabled: " + menu.getItem(0).isEnabled() );
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        String replaceable = String.format("[%s,.\\s]", NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance().getCurrency().getSymbol());

        if(!s.toString().equals(current)){
            txtCost.removeTextChangedListener(this);

            String cleanString = s.toString().replaceAll(replaceable, "");

            double parsed = Double.parseDouble(cleanString);
            String formated = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance().format((parsed/100));

            current = formated;
            txtCost.setText(formated);
            txtCost.setSelection(formated.length());

            txtCost.addTextChangedListener(this);
         }
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
            int after) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** I seem to have stumbled upon a somewhat fix, but it is pretty dirty.

In the MainActivity that houses the fragments, in onTabSelected I placed a call to invalidateContextMenu, then I moved the inflater to the MainActivity as well, checking which tab is selected. This makes the menu draw much quicker, but seems like a very strange way to have to do it.

Are there any downsides to using this method?

Comment: try moving `setHasOptionsMenu(true);` to `onCreate()` of fragment.

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't seem to have much (any) effect on the behavior. It still occurs. It's strange because there's no set pattern to it. The only thing that is for sure is if I click the tab, it will always show, but sliding is hit and miss.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set your viewpager offset limit to no of tabs you have,

like i had 3

```
viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);
```